# How to remove clipping in a Flutter ListView?

Tags: listview, dart, stack, flutter, clipping

I have the following layout, a `Stack` with a `ListView` beneath it, both inside a `Column`.

When I scroll the `ListView`, as expected it clips itself, within its own box.

I want the `ListView`, when scrolling to move up and over the `Stack` above. Like it isn't being clipped at its boundaries.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

in listview add

```
clipBehavior: Clip.none
```

Comment: In a normal ListView the clipBehavior: Clip.none will do the trick, not clipping the ListView content.
For the situation you describe, however, you need a CustomScrollView like described below...

Answer (score 2):

You will need a `CustomScrollView`, and your header widget must be placed in a `SliverPersistentHeader`:

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            delegate: MyHeader(),
            pinned: true,
          ),
          SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('Test $index'),
            );
          }))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHeader extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
   return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 100.0;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 100.0;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image]

---

To create a floating `AppBar`, use the `SliverAppBar` widget:

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('Flutter Playground'),
            pinned: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
          SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('Test $index'),
            );
          }))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]